# Updating table values based on positive of negative

Tags: kdb, qsqlquery

I'm attempting to categorise trades in a query based on whether they are a long (+ve value) or short(-ve value)

```
q)R:select sum size by sym from update size:neg size from trades where trades[`side]=`sell
q)R
sym | size
----| ------
AAPL| 22321
CSCO| -20790
DELL| -53614
GOOG| 62652
IBM | 77839
MSFT| -40878
NOK | 14767
ORCL| -53922
```

I've managed to get to here but I can't seem to update the positive size values with long and negative with short without getting error messages. 
Failed attempts to convert the +ve values look similar to this

```
update size:`long from R where size>0
update size:`long from R where R[`size]>0
```

Answer (score 1):

The update is failing because you are trying to update some of a column that is of long type to a symbol type, this results in a mixed list:

```
q)update size:?[size>0;`long;`short] from R
```

Comment: It is failing because Qbie is only updating some of the values which results in a mixed list. It is possible to change a long column to a symbol column.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly faster version:

```
q) update new_size:`short`long size>0 from R
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth noting that null `0n` is treated less-than any number, if `R` contains nulls then it will default to `short` which in some cases gives you unintentional results.

The following null check will take care of that edge case.

```
q)update size:?[null size;`;?[size>0;`long;`short]] from R
```

However, in some cases, it might be perfectly fine to default to either long or short.